# Write a program that prompts the user for the radius of a sphere and prints its volume

Tags: c, floating-point, division, integer-division

Im not getting correct answer with the following code below. Can anyone debug this code?
When I input radius = 5, the answer I get is 500.000000 whereas the original answer should be 523.80952. Can anyone please explain what's wrong here?

Sphere volume formula =4/3(π x r^3)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()


    {
    float radius = 0;
    float volume;
    float pie = 0;

    printf("Enter radius");
    scanf("%f", &radius);

    pie = 22 / 7;

    volume = (4*pie*radius*radius*radius)/3;
    printf("the volume is %f", volume);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "the original answer should be 523.80952". No, it should be more like `523.598776` (to 6 decimal places). 22/7 is a poor approximation to π. I'd suggest using a more accurate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write `pie = 3.14 ;` instead of `pie = 22 / 7 ;`

And keep in mind that:
(a) Arithmetic operation between two integers always returns an integer.
(b) Arithmetic operation between two real numbers always returns a real number.
(c) Arithmetic operation between an integer and a real number returns a real number.

So, `pie = 22 / 7` will return 500.000000 instead of 523.80952.
therefore you can also write `pie = 22.0 / 7` or `pie = 22 / 7.0` or `pie = 22.0 / 7.0`. These three will return the original answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line

```
 pie = 22 / 7;
```

here, both the operands of the division being integer constants, this is an integer division and the the result get assigned to `float`, which is not what you want. You need to *force* a floating point division by saying

```
pie = ((float)22) / 7;
```

Comment: If both the operands are integer, will I always get an integer value?

Comment: Curious, why call `22` an _integer literal_ vs maybe _integer constant_?

Comment: @chux Well, i don't think [integer literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal) is incorrect use, but as per the standard, it's integer constant. Edited anyway.

Comment: Of course, `22.0f / 7.0f` or even just `22.0f / 7` should work as well. I personally find that a tad more elegant than casting to float.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I agree. The term "literal" is quite common, not only in C. If, like me, you work in different languages, especially if in one of them a constant is something different (an *identifier* like `circumference` representing a literal like `17`) you tend to use the term "literal" for, well, literal values.